# how to call cosine and sine function in .html.erb file?

Tags: ruby, math, trigonometry

My  form calls trig functions like sin and cos, but I'm unable to compile it ; it keeps returning me this error message

```
undefined method `cos' for #<#<Class:0x10345d6d0>:0x1034488c0>
```

How can I fix this error ?

I am unable to paste my code to this window, but I have "include Math" and

```
<% @project.UsableArea = @project.DevelopableRoofArea / (cos(@project.TiltAngle) + 3 * sin(@project.TiltAngle)) %>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to prefix the `cos` and `sin` methods with the module name:

Example:

```
<%= Math.cos(0.5) %>
```

In your case:

```
<% @project.UsableArea = @project.DevelopableRoofArea / (Math.cos(@project.TiltAngle) + 3 * Math.sin(@project.TiltAngle)) %>
```